# Add multiple user-selected attachments to email

Tags: php, html

I am implementing basic email capabilities for administrators on my site. They can set the subject, content, etc and then send out the mail to specified recipients. The problem I'm having is with the attachments. They should be able to select multiple files  **that is already on the webserver** (public_html/fileuploads/myfile.pdf for example).

If it cannot be attached from the webserver, then I need to at least implement a way they can attach multiple files from their PC. Currently I'm using Swiftmailer and it accepts attachments like this:

```
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/file.pdf'));
```

So I need the user to be able to select multiple files. This I can accomplish with:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple/>
```

But now I don't know how to get the full path of each selected file, and then add each file as an attachment. It should be submitted from the HTML to my mailer.php page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Im not 100% sure, but if memory serves me right, if you access the file stream on your PHP script, you wouldnt have to save it to your server (regarding the file upload)

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How to handle file-uploads, or how to let a user pick files from the server to use in an attachment? The 2 storylines are intertwined in your posting. Could you clarify a little?

Comment: Okay, so I guess what I need is how to get the full path of all the files selected by the user in the file upload dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// first get a list of the attachments
$attachments_dir = 'public_html/fileuploads';
$attachments = glob("$attachments_dir/*.pdf");

// then put them into the form
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="attachments[]" value="',$attachment], '">',$attachment,'<br />'; 
 }


// then when the form is submitted, use them
$selected_attachments = $_POST['attachments'];
foreach ($selected_attachments as $attachment) {
  $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($attachment));
}
```

Keep in mind while this shows the process you want to go through it is not very secure.
Someone could change the attachment to /root/secretpasswords.txt for example and you could attach something not expected.

If all the attachments are in a single directory only, you could just use the filename part rather then the path/filename in the submission form, but this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You will get filename & tmp file source in php as below

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);$i++)  
{  
  if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i] != "")  
  {  
    //here you will get all files selected by user.
    echo $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    echo $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i] 

    //here you can copy files to your server, then pass one to your swift mailer function.
    //to copy file to your server, you can use copy() or move_upload_file() function.
  }  
}
```